# Clear an Android application of all Activity's (above/launched by, and including the main launched one)

Tags: android, terminate, back-stack

I have a root activity which of necessity is defined `singleTop`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have a notification that sends a broadcast to my foreground service telling it, and the Activity if it is bound to `MyMainActivity`, to stop. A widget can be touched to restore `MyMainActivity` to its previous state, hence the need for `singleTop`.

The problem is that since introducing the stop service button on the notification (de rigeur, as I understand) it is killing just `MyMainActivity` meaning that any `Activity`s started from it will persist, as I intended it, but fail to return meaningful results since their originating, `MyMainActivity` has already been destroyed.

I've stuck with a simple `finish()` to handle the termination broadcast from `MyMainActivity`, after disconnecting from the service. All the other `finish` variants had undesired side effects.

`System.exit(0);` does actually work great. Except that the expected life cycle course towards destruction gets ignored and restarting is a bit of a bother.

`finishAffinity` is another candidate, except it is described:

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it

when I need to finish the activities above it, according to the android dev terminology.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, and has been since API 1. Call `finishActivity(int intent_id)` with the same `intent_id` that was supplied to `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`.